# Run a c program in terminal on mac

Tags: c, macos

I can compile c source into binary by going into terminal and type `gcc <filename>`. This renders the output file in the respective directory. But what if I want to interact with the file? I have a simple c program which asks for user input then provides out based on my input. How do I execute this code in terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default filename is `a.out`. If you want to run it, just type `./a.out`.

If you want a different filename use `-o`. 
That is, run `gcc -o MyOutName <filename>`.

Comment: Cool. So this can run on any unix machine, but not on Windows I presume?

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4, Assuming that the version of the libraries that the executable was compiled against is available on the target system, yes. That is not always a safe assumption though, especially if you take on outside library dependencies.

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4, It is exactly for this reason that many packages with a binary distribution will have a separate one for OS X and Unix, as well as for Windows.

Comment: If you have source code in c is it fairly easy to compile is in each one of those different distributions? Or would you need to change the code to adjust for the compiler in any way?

Comment: If your code is standards compliant and doesn't depend on compiler extensions or platform apis then yes.